# How to parse JSON and access a value

Tags: json, ruby

From this,

```js
{
  “students”: [
    {
      “name”: “test1”,
      "id": 1,
      "created_at": "2019-03-13T21:34:30Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-03-13T21:34:30Z",
      “title”: "My test ticket2",
      "description": “My test description!”
     }
  ],
  "count": 1
}
```

How can I get the value of id, description and count? I did:

```rb
JSON.parse(response)
```

but I am not sure how to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse returns hash.

**Fetching information about student**:

```
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
parsed_response['students'].first['id']
parsed_response['students'].first['name']
parsed_response['students'].first['description']
```

If you have more than one values, iterate over them with `each`.

**Fetching count**:

```
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
parsed_response['count']
```

Instead of `[]` you can use [fetch](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/fetch) (`parsed_response.fetch('students')`). Please keep in mind, that `fetch` raises an error when the key is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse twice, if you just parse once you will get the error:
`TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String`

you should do like that:

```rb
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.to_json)
```

Then you can get the values as you need:

```rb
parsed_response['students'][0]['id']
```

You can also use the [dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method if your ruby version is higher than 2.3:

```rb
parsed_response.dig('students', 0, 'id')
=> 1
```